# Unzip a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying two print the columns individually of a variable I obtained  by applying a function from zipping two variables. Please find below:

```
x5 = list(zip(x3,x4))
x6 = np.array(x5)
print(x6)
```

Applying the function:

```
n = 1 
br = myfunction(x3,x4,n)

print('this is the result ... ',  br)
```

Note as suggested, a reproducible way of generating data of the type myfunction outputs is:

```
   br = numpy.random.rand((5, 2))
```

Output looks like this :

```
finally result ... [[[5.37692693e+03 3.78425697e- 
 03]
  [1.36092539e+03 3.35722632e-03]
  [5.43477586e+03 3.90104194e-03]
   ...
  [5.93759455e+03 4.05490440e-03]
  [3.00855802e+03 3.65746871e-03]
  [4.69875286e+03 3.93713784e-03]]]
```

I have tried many methods such as: 
First:

```
  x10,x11 = zip(*br)
  print(x10,x11) /print(np.array(x10),np.array(x11))
```

Hasn't worked giving the error (too many values to unpack two are expected)

Second:

```
def column(matrix,i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]

 x10 = column(br,0)
 x11 = column(br,1)

 print(x10,x11)
```

For which the output is :

```
 [array([5.37692693e+03, 3.78425697e-03])] 
 [array([1.36092539e+03, 3.35722632e-03])]
```

and third:

```
   x11 = [i[0] for i in br]
   x12 = [i[1] for i in br]
   print(x11.split(),x12.split())
```

I believe this aren't working because the output of my function is of type [[[....]]]

Many thanks

Comment: Why have you used `()` twice in `x6 = np.array((x5))` and what is `myfunction`?

Comment: I am using one () in my code and I still have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: `myfunction` is irrelevant to this question. Remove it in favor of a reproducible way of generating data, e.g. `br = numpy.random.rand((5, 2))` or whatever the shape of `br` is in your example.

Comment: Many thanks Nils will do. That's an excellent tip to use in future questions. New to stackoverflow and coding :)

Comment: @NilsWerner `np.random.rand((5, 2))` yields an error - do you mean `np.random.rand(5, 2) `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only ever unpack the first dimension of an array, but the dimension you want to unpack is the second one. This means in your case, you can do:

```
x10, x11 = br.T
```

Be aware that `x10` and `x11` will be [a view into `br`](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html)! This means if you change any of the values in any of these arrays, you will change the other variables too.

If your array has more than 2D dimensions (extra `[` and `]`), check the shape of your array using

```
br.shape
```

and if you see superfluous empty dimensions (`1`), remove them using

```
br = br.squeeze()
```

Comment: Awesome finally getting the two separate columns. Nice and simple thanks! The result is now giving  for example column 1 : [[5376.92693]
 [1360.92539]
 [5434.77586]
 ...
 [5937.59455]
 [3008.55802]
 [4698.75286]].Do you know how could I get rid of the [] in each value such that would give an array like [5376.92693, 1360.92539,...]?

Comment: Yup, as the answer says: `br.squeeze()` them

Comment: Yes sorry I hadn't refreshed the page :)

Comment: I have added information about NumPy views and that changing any of the variables will also change the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is

```
br = [[[5.37692693e+03, 3.78425697e-03],  [1.36092539e+03, 3.35722632e-03],  [5.43477586e+03, 3.90104194e-03],  [5.93759455e+03, 4.05490440e-03],  [3.00855802e+03, 3.65746871e-03],  [4.69875286e+03, 3.93713784e-03]]]

x10,x11 = zip(*br[0])
print(x10,x11)
```

**Output**

```
(5376.92693, 1360.92539, 5434.77586, 5937.59455, 3008.55802, 4698.75286) (0.00378425697, 0.00335722632, 0.00390104194, 0.0040549044, 0.00365746871, 0.00393713784)
```

Comment: Don't do this, it will copy the data from a NumPy view to a tuple, which will be very inefficient for large arrays.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the info. I will leave the answer as it is instead of deleting it so that people who do it this way can read your comment and get some info :)